# Can't commit folder to svn from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have added two folders to xcode project and now when I try to commit them I get following error:

```
'/Users/me/demo/app/app/MyFolderName' 
is not known to exist in the repository and is not part of the commit,
yet its child 
'/Users/me/demo/app/app/MyFolderName/RequestOperation.h' 
is part of the commit
```

I have tried:

```
svn add MyFolderName
```

But I get:

```
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for adding, are you giving complete path of the folder like:

```
svn add /Users/me/demo/app/app/MyFolderName
```

Comment: Now I get: `svn: E155007: '/Users/me' is not a working copy`. In xcode commiting of other files work but in console when I type that command I get this error.

Comment: replace me with your system login name.

Comment: I did it. I didn't try to use 'me' I typed my login name.

Comment: from terminal go to the parent folder of your svn unrevisioned folder.  Now try svn add yourNewFolder  `Like: if your path is /Users/me/demo/app/app/Newfolder`  In termial,  `$ cd /Users/me/demo/app/app`  `$ svn add Newfolder`

Comment: Now I get `svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation`

Comment: within this new folder, some folder may be containing .svn files  
navigate to each folder within new folder and check `$ ls -a`.  
if you find .svn files there then remove those files.  after removing all files try the above steps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54634/discussion-between-ganeshios-and-1110).

Comment: hah funny from XCode it doesn't work. But now I used `svn commit -m ""` and it worked :)